# How to send daily top-side adjustments to QuickBooks?

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Our business processes credit card orders using a Wells Fargo merchant account and Authorize.net. The import works great each day into our Income/Product Sales account.

Now we would like to add a daily, automated, top-side entry to split this income line out to Product Sales-CATEGORY A and Product Sales-Category B.

So this would be like:

| Date | Account | Dr | Cr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Product Sales | 50,000 |  |
| 2022-01-01 | Product Sales-CATEGORY A |  | 10,000 |
| 2022-01-01 | Product Sales-CATEGORY B |  | 40,000 |

I can have our order processing system calculate this figure each day and present it/send it in any format.

Is it possible to flow that into QuickBooks?

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried so far? How is this related to PHP?

Comment: The server runs PHP. I have read the QuickBooks API and website. The QuickBooks website says to post the question here.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should even contain your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: A Google search yields tons and tons of information on this topic - you should start there, and then when you have technical questions you should come back here with those questions: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=quickbooks+php  Additionally, you're going to need to specify if you are talking about QuickBooks ONLINE, QuickBooks for MAC, or QuickBooks for WINDOWS (they are all different products, with different APIs)